# Cassandra how to silently fail and not connect to inactive node

Tags: python, database, cassandra, database-connection

I am having an issue with cassandra python library. I have a 3 node cluster, to which I am connecting to by using following code: -

```
self.cassandra_cluster = Cluster(self.cassandra_cluster_nodes)
self.cassandra_session = self.cassandra_cluster.connect(self.keyspace)
```

where `self.cassandra_cluster_nodes` is list of nodes, and `self.keyspace` is the keyspace.

Now all was working fine, suddenly, one of my cassandra cluster nodes dies. Now code is constantly trying to reconnect to a dead node. I am unable to figure out how to ignore a dead node, and only consider the active nodes.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html